# How to get values from pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, controller

Hi I'm trying to create a table that only displays users from the correct school. The school id function works. I just need to replace the "#school id" placeholder I placed in the where clause with the data from the pivot table seen at the bottom of the screenshot. As I want to compare the school id in the pivot table to the school id I've provided. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $school_id = Auth::user()->schools[0]->id;
    $users_in_school = User::all()->load('schools')->where('#school id?','=',$school_id);
    return $users_in_school;
```

[image: Data]

Comment: This is where you use `whereHas()`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence. Also, never start your query with `User::all()`; that immediately loads _all_ records from the DB into memory, and you can't chain query methods.

Comment: Oh ok, I`ve never heard of that before. Would I implement it something like this? Also, I'm mainly struggling with how to even access the data from the pivot table

$users_in_school=User::whereHas('schools', function (Builder $query){
            $query->where('school_id','like',$school_id);
        })->get();

Comment: You want to get all the user connected to the given school_id ?

Comment: I`ve got it working now thanks 

$users_in_school=User::whereHas('schools', function ($query){
            $school_id = Auth::user()->schools[0]->id;
            $query->where('school_id',$school_id);
        })->get();

Comment: But yeah that's what I wanted to do @xenooooo if there is a better way of doing that?

Comment: Yeah, I was going to ask why you were using `LIKE` here. You could also simply do `School::findOrFail($schoolId)->users`, assuming you have the inverse relationship set up (you didn't include your Models, so I can only guess), and it will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Ok, thanks yeah I'm not sure I tried to look up how to use it and the examples had that. But then realised I didn't need it. Ill look into your findOrFail suggestion now aswell thanks

Answer (score 0):

The working code after help from @Tim Lewis

```
  $users_in_school=User::whereHas('schools', function ($query){
        $school_id = Auth::user()->schools[0]->id;
        $query->where('school_id',$school_id);
    })->get();
```